# <map object at 0x7f07ab32b2d0> error shows while printing list of map function,I want to print arr list to screen

Tags: list, function, dictionary, map-function, map-files

```
n = int(input())
arr = map(int, input().split())
print(arr) #error here
```

I have map function that splits out list items by comma.

I want to print out arr that contains list.

Then I have to find second highest number from the list.

Can you help?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please add an appropriate tag for the programming language or framework you are using?4

Comment: Its Python 3,Thanks for your concerns, it been solved

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(arr)
```

define arr as a list.